# Get ACF WooCommerce product value from order Item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, orders

I'm using Woocommerce and when the payment is being made, this function is executed and it works correctly, but what I need is for the value of the custom field to be returned when executing the foreach. What function returns the content of the field, I tried `the_field('comboitems')` but without success.

```
function example_metadata( $metadata, $order, $post  ) {
  foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $metadata['test'] = '1234';
        $metadata['field1'] = $item->get_data();
        $metadata['customfield'] = the_field('comboitems');
  }
  return $metadata;
}
```

This `$item->get_data()` was an attempt to check if the comboitems custom field was read.

I used the command `$item->get_data();` in an attempt to see if it returned something related to my field.. I tried using the_field('comboitems') but it returned NULL, as well as other variations in search of a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `the_field()` function as it echoes a custom field. Use instead `get_field()` to assign a custom field value to a variable…

Then from an order item (product), you will use:

```
$metadata['customfield'] = get_field('comboitems', $item->get_product_id());
```

So in your code:

```
function example_metadata( $metadata, $order, $post  ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $metadata['customfield'] = get_field('comboitems', $item->get_product_id());
    }
    return $metadata;
}
```

Comment: LoicTheAztec, how can I make when don't is custom field but an attribute?

Comment: It depends if you want to get a specific attribute value from a variation of a variable product, or a specific attribute of a product… Try to be more explicit.

Comment: for this case even where you got the field value, for that same field there is an attribute, I want to return it in the same way that the field content was returned.

Comment: @teclesoft Sorry, I don't catch… Maybe you should ask a new question trying to explain things the more clearly that you can, providing the code you tried (even if it doesn't work) and notify me here with the link of that new question. Then I will try to answer it.

Comment: Ok, follow the link. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77782109/get-attribute-of-product`