# Get WooCommerce product attribute value from Order item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

Read attribute content of a product.
I am including within the JSON of the order that is being processed in WooCommerce the value of the attribute of the product that is being processed, I have already managed to get the content of a custom field see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77759086/get-acf-woocommerce-product-value-from-order-item/77760942), but I have not yet been able to get the content of an attribute that it would even be from this same product.

```
function example_metadata( $metadata, $order, $post  ) {
  foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) { 
        $metadata['atrib'] =$item->get_product_id()->get_attribute( 'split' );
        $product = wc_get_product();
        $metadata['atrib1'] = $item_id->get_attribute( 'split' );
  }
  return $metadata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `get_attribute()` is a `WC_Product` method, it has to be used with a `WC_Product` Object…

Try the following instead:

```php
function example_metadata( $metadata, $order, $post  ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $value   = $product->get_attribute('split');
        if ( $item->get_variation_id() > 0 && empty($value) ) {
           $product = wc_get_product($item->get_product_id());
           $value   = $product->get_attribute('split');
        }
        $metadata['atrib'] = $value;
    }
    return $metadata;
}
```

It could work.

If it doesn't work, try to use the product attribute **label name** instead of the slug, maybe like "Split" instead of "split".